# UITextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero in layoutSubviews doesn't work in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, uitextview

I have a `PopupView` that extends `UIView`. In `PopupView` I have a `UITextView`.
When the `PopupView` show, my `UITextView` doesn't start at first line (it scroll a little bit to bottom)
So I use the code below to scroll the `UITextView` to top after `PopupView` appears

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self.contentTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

It works well in iOS9 (both device and simulator) but it doesn't work in iOS8
Any idea to fix it.
Any help would be great appreciated

**UPDATE**

I found that `drawRect` get called after layoutSubviews and if I `setContentOffset:CGPointZero` inside it, it will work

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [self.contentTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
}
```

But I found the purpose of `drawRect`:

> drawRect: - Implement this method if your view draws custom content.
>   If your view does not do any custom drawing, avoid overriding this
>   method.

Is it good to use `drawRect` without `layoutSubviews` in my case?

Comment: Try it on `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: @longpham I put it in `awakeFromNib` and it doesn't work in both iOS8 and iOS9

Comment: Can you show the screenshot for your issue.

Comment: I didn't get it before. Can you share your custom `PopupView`.

Comment: @longpham my popupview now has many code :( here is not a popupview but it is my demo about textview
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_poNaia6t8kV3MtODM5TjdhUTQ/view
if you run it you will see the textview not start from top

Comment: @longpham i have same problem as https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=textview%20not%20start%20from%20top

Comment: Ok. I will have a look.

Comment: `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews { [self.myTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}` Try it in your view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111609/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-longpham).

Answer (score 2):

According to @longpham instruction, the `drawRect()` will use GPU so it's not good. Here is the solution that solve my problem

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self layoutIfNeeded]; // call layoutIfNeeded here to make layoutSubviews get called whenever layout change
}
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    ...
    [self.contentTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    self.textView=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

    [self addSubview:self.textView];

}
```

Comment: did you check in iOS8?

Comment: it work but my current textview is in the xib file. do you have any solution for me to continue use the textview in xib file

Comment: After loading the textView  from Xib .You have to  change the frame . And it has worked for me